# C Error: free(): invalid next size (fast):, different behaviour of C program on OSX, Linux

Tags: c, linux, macos

This question has been asked several times, but since I think my situation is I think more specific:

I have a C program, which works perfectly on my OSX system (too huge to copy). I already tested it with Valgrind, and I am not missing any frees /mallocs /or writes, all problems are solved 100%.

When I now run the program over ssh on an external sever, when I run with not that many data (see code below, my_length < 1000), it works without any problem. But with a larger dataset, using the Linux terminal I get this error:

```
 *** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00000000016b9ed0 ***
 ======= Backtrace: =========
 /lib64/libc.so.6[0x3e50475cff]
 /lib64/libc.so.6[0x3e5047cff8]
 ./a.out[0x41083c]
 ./a.out[0x402374]
 /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x3e50421d65]
 ./a.out[0x400e79]
 ======= Memory map: ========
  00400000-00418000 r-xp 00000000 00:4d 89038
```

[...]

and when I run it on Solaris it complains :

```
malloc failed
```

at a line where I allocate a three dimensional array:

```
 int ***A, ***B, ***C;
 A = malloc(sizeof(int**)*2); B = malloc(sizeof(int**)*2); C = malloc(sizeof(int**)*2);
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    A[i] = malloc(sizeof(int*)* my_length);
    B[i] = malloc(sizeof(int*)* my_length);
    C[i] = malloc(sizeof(int*)* my_length);
    for (j = 0; j <= my_length2; j++) {
        A[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(int)* my_length2);
        B[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(int)* my_length2);
        C[i][j] = malloc(sizeof(int)* my_length2);<== malloc failed here??
    }   
}
```

where `my_length` and `my_length2` get really really huge!

I am getting desperate! Does someone have any clue what my problem could be?

Comment: `j <= my_length2` should much rather be `j < my_length`. Think about what your array indexing means/does.

Comment: Yes you are right, but this is a miss-typing here, it is right in my code

Comment: What are the values of `my_length` and `my_length2`? Are you trying to allocate more memory than the operating system allows?

Comment: >50000 approximately, I think there should be enough space available for this. Shouldn't there be an error if I want to allocate "to much" memory

Comment: Yet Another Three Start Programmer. YATSP

Comment: The code shown does not check any allocations for validity.  You never know whether the `malloc()` calls succeed.  That said, you'd normally get a crash if you access the null pointer returned on allocation failure, so maybe it doesn't matter for this purpose, but it is not a good way of organizing code in general.

Comment: After each   p=malloc(nbytes)  call, check p for being NULL. This happens iff malloc() fails to allocate the desired memory block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are so many duplicates found for this question that annoyingly, I cannot find the right one for you.

The basic problem is that your program **has most definitely** written over the memory block tracking information that the malloc/free library uses.

Somewhere in your program is a memory write that is out of bounds.

Comment: It could even be the use of `j <= my_length2` for the inner loop. It should indeed be `j <= my_length`, as @TheParamagneticCroissant noticed.

Comment: You mean, somewhere I allocate to less memory and then I try to write over it?

But how can it be, that this error occurs just sometimes, shouldn't it then occur every time when I start the program?? And shouldn't valgrind find the write error ?

Comment: What exactly happens is undefined, but it could be that what actually happens is dependent on the state of your machine, i.e. what else is loaded and running, etc.

Comment: @malajedala: Sometimes malloc allocates more memory than you ask for. That can reduce fragmentation and improves memory access alignment. In those cases you can write past the end without crashing. In other cases the memory allocation was exactly what you asked for and there is no extra room.

Comment: Ahh ok, yes you are right... So how could I possibly find this mistake :S?

Answer (score -1):

Ok I found one possible solution, I was increasing my values step by step, and now valgrind reports following:

```
==3954== Invalid write of size 8
==3954==    at 0x344C1B: _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Unknown (in       /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib)
==3954==    by 0x1C4D74: __memcpy_chk (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==3954==    by 0x10000B2E4: my_method (delete.c:1461)
==3954==    by 0x1000025B3: main (delete.c:365)
==3954==  Address 0x1020611a0 is 16 bytes after a block of size 2,096 alloc'd
==3954==    at 0x56AA: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:698)
==3954==    by 0x10000B21E: my_method (delete.c:1458)
==3954==    by 0x1000025B3: main (delete.c:365)
```

And this is the code, because I have no idea why this appears:S

```
if (temp_length + strlen(new_substring)
                > max_seq_lens[i]) {

            max_len[i] *= 2;
            my_array[i].name = realloc(sizeof(char)* max_seq_lens[i]); <=== 
        }
 temp_length += (some_num);
```

SO here temp_length is saving the current length of my my_array[i].name, I am trying to concatenate a new string (new_substring) and before I concatenate them, I tried to check if the memory is enough,  I really don't see my mistake here :S

Comment: This isn't an answer. And look at the variable names your code uses. I think you're using the wrong arrays. Cut and paste error?